# cant make a button rotate its parent column with javascript in elementor

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to insert JS code to elementor in order to make a column rotate on a button click
created this code:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
$('.blog_click').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
document.getElementById(".column_rotate").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";}
} else {
        $(this).addClass('active')
}
</script>
```

but it didnt work for some reason...
anyone have any idea ?

Comment: `document.getElementById(".column_rotate")` I guess that `.column_rotate` is not valid ID. Show us working snippet with HTML please.

Comment: thats inside of elementor so its the only thing written

Comment: i tried changing the id to "ccrr" and still didnt work

Comment: `.column_rotate` is NOT an ID, it is a class name. Class names begin with a period `.` and IDs begin with a hash `#`.

Comment: @hungerstar you are right, but yet even after corecting this it didnt work

Comment: You need to provide more code so everyone can have a better idea of the full context and how things relate. Also, if possible, create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How do we know that you corrected it properly without seeing how you corrected it?

Comment: i complitly understand but i dont really know how... im not a programmer and i dont know how to create the whole HTML to do what i did in elementor...just trying to add the JS to make that animation happen...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, "Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com)."